# Why adding two List[Map[String, Any]] changes the output result type to List[Equals] in scala?

Tags: scala

following is REPL commands

```
scala> val x = (
if(1==1) { 
  List("a"->1, "b"->"t") 
} else {
  List.empty[Map[String, Any]]
}
) ::: (
if(2==2) { 
  List("c"->1, "d"->"t")
} else {
  List.empty[Map[String, Any]]
})

// Output
x: List[Equals] = List((a,1), (b,t), (c,1), (d,t))

// needed output
x: List[Map[String, Any]]= List(Map("a"->1, "b"->"t", "c"->1, "d"->"t"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason is because it's the common trait between `List[Tuple2]` and `List[Map[String, Any]]`.

If you did something like this, the types would align:

```
val x = (
  if (1 == 1) {
    List(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> "t"))
  } else {
    List.empty[Map[String, Any]]
  }) ::: (
  if (2 == 2) {
    List(Map("c" -> 1, "d" -> "t"))
  } else {
    List.empty[Map[String, Any]]
  }
)
```

**UPDATE**: If you really need to have as a result a `List` with a single `Map` in it, you could adapt the above code by reducing the `List`:

```
val x = List(
  (
    (if (1 == 1) {
       List(Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> "t"))
     } else {
       List.empty[Map[String, Any]]
     })
    :::
    (if (2 == 2) {
       List(Map("c" -> 1, "d" -> "t"))
     } else {
       List.empty[Map[String, Any]]
     })
  ).reduce(_ ++ _)
)
```

Beware of concatenating `Map` though, since overlapping keys would override one another. To overcome that, you'd need to use the combine function of the `Semigroup` typeclass. Note that you'd need to provide evidence that the values in the `Map` also conform to a `Semigroup`.

Comment: Why not `Map(...)` instead of `List(...).toMap`?

Comment: I need final result like List(Map("a"->1, "b"->"t", "c"->1, "d"->"t")) above solution is giving me List(Map(a -> 1, b -> t), Map(c -> 1, d -> t))

Comment: Is there a reason why you need a `List` with a single `Map` in it? If what you are really interested in is the `Map`, I'd suggest using `reduce`.